# iOS: Core Location know when user location found

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have created a `locationManager` object, set all of the options, including delegate. I am getting back location updates, which is great.  But, how can I know when `location services` has found my users location? Sometimes if I move to a location away from cell service, it takes a while to get a fix.  Since I am not using `MapKit`, I don't see a method to know if I have not found the users location yet.

This question is NOT about `MapKit`, only about `CoreLocation`.  I know that `MKMapViewDelegate` has the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method, but I am not using a MapView for this app.

Is there any such method?  Or do I need to add a hidden `MKMapView` or something in order to use `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`?

Answer (score 0):

The user's position can change over time.  The accuracy of the reading can change over time.  There's no single discrete point in time where the user is "found", it's just a constantly changing measurement.

If you are using Core Location, then the messages passed to your delegate include `CLLocation` objects which have horizontal and vertical accuracy readings.  If you want to know when the user's location can be measured within a certain degree of accuracy, you can use those.  But you should be aware that these are measurements that can move in and out of your tolerance levels without warning.  This is not a binary found/not found situation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I realize about the accuracy of locations, and have used CoreLocation and MapKit extensively already so I know and understand the variables involved here. My question is specifically about when a location/fix takes a long time to be found, such as when you turn off the device, and travel a few hours into a place with only GPS. I need to know when a fix is finally gotten. Possibly the first non-cached location from locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:?

Comment: That depends on your meaning of the word "fix".  The first result will often be made through Wi-Fi base station identification, not through GPS.  This could potentially be on the wrong continent.  The first GPS result is likely to be inaccurate, but nowhere near as bad.  The subsequent GPS results will probably be more accurate.  If you want long enough, you could get a location that is accurate to within a few metres.

Comment: All of these situations could reasonably be considered "getting a fix", depending on the nature of the application, which is why the *single point* that you are asking about doesn't exist.  It's up to you to decide when it's accurate enough.

Comment: Ok. I guess my next question is. I have been in places where it takes 3 minutes to finally find my location in the Maps app (fly into another country with no cell service). During the time it is trying to find my location, do you think that location services is actually returning locations, but just with really bad accuracy?

Comment: The device needs to lock onto three satellites to get a position.  It also needs up to date ephemeris data for each of them.  If you haven't used your GPS in the area in the past couple of hours, you'll probably have to wait to receive new data.  If your device can't connect to three satellites, this will further delay any location tracking.

Comment: The reason I ask this entire question is I want to hide a specific part of the UI until I have a location. I think that I will conclude I have found the user location on my first "good" location update in locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:. By "good", I mean I have a filtering algorithm for this, which takes accuracy into account, so if it allows a location through, it will be a good ones based on my filtering. So I am thinking this might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two good articles worth reviewing:
[How to effectively use Core Location in your iPhone app](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/325-how-to-effectively-use-core-location-in-your-iphone-app/)
and
[Getting iPhone Location Information using the iOS 4 Core Location Framework](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Getting_iPhone_Location_Information_using_the_iOS_4_Core_Location_Framework#Accuracy)

In the second article, you will see the accuracy described, and the accuracy is estimated in the property values `CLLocation verticalAccuracy` and `CLLocation horizontalAccurcy`

Check the [documentation for CLLocation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126) for more details.

While you can tell location services what accuracy you want to achieve, it may not get there, but yoiu should be able to monitor the estimated accuracy values and compare them with a threshold to decide if you are meeting your accuracy requirement.

What this means is that you may need to filter the core location reports before passing location information on to the point where it is needed. That way, you can discard any spurious location information, which can often be generated.

The details of how you handle this will depend on your specific needs, of course.